# Edit permalink for old posts and not show on top of RSS feed

Tags: permalinks, rss, feed

I have edited permalinks for old posts (slug)

After changing slug the posts appear on the top in RSS feed in some services.
But I don't want to get this posts on top, I want just to edit slug.

It seems the reason for this is `guid` tag in RSS, which contains links I have changed:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">
http://host1.com/blog1/slug-of-article
</guid>
```

After changing link some services consider the entry as new post, which seems correct according to the info at http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#element-channel-item-guid

The question is how to avoid such behavior?

Is it possible to configure Wordpress in some way, e.g. generate guid not related to link, using some plug-ins etc...?

If such behavior not possible to avoid for old posts, it would be good to make it possible to avoid such situation for new posts keeping in mind that I may desire to change permalink in future.

Thank in advance,
Sergiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the reason for this is `guid` tag in RSS, which contains links
>   I have changed

If you've changed the `GUID` in the database...

[From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note):

> When doing the above and changing the URLs directly in the database,
>   you will come across instances of the URL being located in the "guid"
>   column in the wp_posts tables.
>
> **It is critical that you do NOT change the contents of this field.**
>
> The term "GUID" stands for "Globally Unique Identifier". It is a field
>   that is intended to hold an identifier for the post which a) is unique
>   across the whole of space and time and b) never, ever changes. The
>   GUID field is primarily used to create the WordPress feeds.
>
> ...
>
> Thus, changing the GUID will mean that many feedreaders will suddenly
>   display your content in the user's reader again as if it was new
>   content, possibly annoying your users.
>
> ...
>
> **Never, ever, change the contents of the GUID column, under any circumstances.**

... then you've broken the mechanism used to prevent this kind of feed "re-publishing".

Unless you have a backup of the database, this may not be fixable. You will need to find all the posts which have had their `guid`s changed and put that `guid` back to exactly what it was before.

Another possibility is that you are constructing the feed incorrectly and are creating this:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">
http://host1.com/blog1/slug-of-article
</guid>
```

... using the post permalink instead of the `guid`. That should be more easily fixable.

Comment: I have not changed guid via Wordpress UI - I event have not found how to do this. I also have not performed changes in mysql tables. I just changed slug for post. But it appear that slug is used as a part of  guid by WP. It seems that I need to change slug but preserve guid as is at the same time - this is to avoid polluting RSS feed with old posts. But I don't know how to achieve this. Feed is constructed by WP - I have not performed some special modifications.

Comment: I obtain such described behavior after importing blog from Blogger

Comment: I have just rechecked. It seems when I update slug/permalink, guid is preserved (old permalink stored in it) - it is fine. It is not clear for me why other posts are moved on top of RSS, possibly something buggy or I do something in wrong way. Anyway I will pay attention to this in future more accurately accounting your clarification. Thanks!

Comment: The `GUID` and the `slug` are different. The `GUID` is created once and never updated after that. The `GUID` ___is not___ an URL, however much it may look like one. It sounds to me like the importer should have preserved the `GUID` used by Blogger (Blogger has to have something of the sort).

Comment: "The GUID is created once and never updated after that" - this is exactly what I have tested right now by changing slug of publication. GUID is preserved.